# Why doesn't the Borel-Kolmogorov paradox cause problems in practice?

Tags: probability, statistics

The Borel-Kolmogorov paradox shows that the usual formula for conditional density $f_{X|Y}(x|y) = f_{X,Y}(x, y)/f_Y(y)$ can lead to inconsistent results depending on the coordinate system that is used to describe the problem [1].

The paradox stems from conditioning on zero probability events being undefined. One explanation comes from considering this conditioning operation, as a limit of distributions that are conditioned on events with non-zero probability. Different limits lead to different conditional densities.

This leaves me with two questions that worry me:

1. When simply applying the "ratio of densities" formula, it's not clear which limit is implied. So two people solving the same problem in different coordinate frames can do the calculation without needing to think about when they can be expected to end up with the same result. **Is there a procedure that makes it clear when two results will end up being different?**
2. How often does this cause a problem in practice? In statistics, we condition on real-valued outcomes all the time! Why do seemingly irrelevant details like the parameterisation not end up causing problems more often? Or is this universally used formula in fact on incredibly shaky ground? To what extent is statistics or Bayesian inference parameterisation independent? In short, **to what extent does this paradox matter in practice?**

From my current (limited) understanding, there is an answer to Question 1. Namely, if you follow the measure-theoretic definition of conditional probability, the choice of $\sigma$-algebra influences the answer. This at least makes it clear where a choice appears, in contrast to following the ratio of densities rule.

[1] See [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PL_L-Sv9p5M) or chapter 15 of Jaynes.

Comment: any two different conditional density all equal almost sure because they are Radon-Nikodym derivatives, as any other integrable function, so they have the same results when are integrated

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're saying that if you integrate these formulas so that you compute a probability conditioned on an event with non-zero probability, then the results would be the same. This is somewhat reassuring, and also demanded by the formal definition of conditional probability.

However, in much of statistics, we work directly with densities conditioned on measure zero events. Maximum likelihood given a specific parameter setting, or Bayesian inference where we condition on observed data. I believe my question still has relevance to these situations.

Comment: yes, your question is relevant when you need to get a consistent value for a probability conditioned to an event of zero measure. I dont know so much of statistics but in stochastic processes some similar things happens, by example in Brownian motion. However there are ways to "model" or interpreted conditional probabilities over events of zero measure as a different process where no conditioning appear at all. Maybe something like this can be applied to other areas as statistics

Comment: Related paper: https://cfreer.org/papers/AckermanFreerRoyCompCondProb.pdf .  Also, your first question reminds me of the [wine/water paradox](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/514557/what-is-the-wine-water-paradox-in-bayesian-statistics-and-what-is-its-resolutio/514582#514582), which may or may not be the same thing.

Comment: I don't know if there is really a canonical answer to this question, but I have always thought of this as being an example of a general phenomenon in probability: paradoxes come from not being careful about what you mean. Borel-Kolmogorov shows an example where two approximation procedures to define the conditional distribution on a lower dimensional object can result in different answers. Whenever you work with a continuous object in practice, there will be an implicit approximation procedure. So long as you are consistent, it doesn't cause problems.